# c++ : Whats difference in "catching reference in value" vs "catching value in value" during function return?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, return-by-reference, return-by-value

What exactly happens at 1 & 2 internally , when we have assigned by return reference?

```
Class A
{
    A& operator= (const A &ax)
    {
        return *this;
    }
}
int main()
{
    A a;
    A b;
    b = a; // -------------- 1
    A c = a;  // ----------- 2
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

What difference will happen in below (assigned returned value)? :

```
Class A
{
    A operator= (const A &ax)
    {
        return *this;
    }
}
int main()
{
    A a;
    A b;
    b = a; // -------------- 3
    A c = a;  // ----------- 4
}
```

Comment: I know assignment and initialisation. But What is difference in internal execution steps of above two samples ?

Comment: @KoolWagh step 1 is calling `b.operator=(a);`. But because step 2 is initialization, not assignment, it does not call your `operator=` at all, it calls the copy constructor instead. `A c = a;` is just syntax sugar for `A c(a);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau But while returning from assignment in First code, reference is returned; while b is not reference. how does it collected in it ? In second case assignment return value and b is value. How will you explain internal differences between two cases ?

Comment: @KoolWagh you are missing the point. The return value of your `A::operator=` is **irrelevant** because your code IS NOT using it for anything at all. Calling `b = a;` is identical to calling `b.operator=(a);`, ignoring the return value. So whether it returns a reference or a value, it doesn't matter. Calling `A c = a;` is identical to calling `A c(a);` so `A::operator=` is not called at all, it calls `A::A(const A&)` instead, so again, the return value of `A::operator=` doesn't matter at all

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah. Thanks Remy. I really was missing that point. The reason is, that in one of my code, i am getting some different values in release mode of vs and debug of mode of vs because of reference return. Issue gets fixed when I return by value. Code is exactly same as above with few member variables. I still dont understand the reason behind it. But anyway thanks for clearing this point.

Comment: @RemyLebeau why you say that b = a; does not use operator= here? There is also principal mistake, because operator= made private and code is ill-formed, but this would be corrected, operator= is called (and obviously it doesn't do assignment, because object that invokes operator is the left one)

Comment: They have exactly the same effect, because neither will compile. Read: [MCVE]

Comment: Difference will only be visible in expressions like `c = b = a` (`c.operator=(b.operator(a))`). Try in both case of your `operator=` (step 1 and 3) and you will see.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès You are right. But private function is just typo. I dint mean for it. But, thanks. I realised it consciously now.

Comment: Even in public case... That is not the problem. One is return by value the other reference return.

Comment: @Swift "*why you say that `b = a;` does not use `operator=` here?*" - that is NOT what I said. Go re-read my comments again more carefully.

Comment: @Swift I was pointing out that it's vague and can be understood that way, because you said that it ignores it. As to big picture, it would be ignored because of optimization (possibly), though to my knowledge unoptimized code still contains those actions. From formal point of view it is still used, though return of reference or value doesn't matter in this particular case because of RVO and resulting value isn't used in any way.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau OP thought that return value of operator= is what assigned to left expression, so your comment went over head, probably.

Answer (score 0):

There is also principal mistake, because `operator=` made private and code is ill-formed, but this would be corrected by adding `public:` access modifiers.

`operator=` is invoked from object stored to `b` variable, so this variant of assignment should not perform assignment at all.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    float a1;

    A& operator= (const A &ax)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a; 
    a.a1 = 3;

    A b; 
    b.a1 = 5;

    b = a; // -------------- 1

    std::cout << b.a1; // outputs 5

    A c = a;
    std::cout << c.a1; // outputs 3

}
```

The line

```
A c = a;
```

is called initialization and doesn't use `operator=`, instead it uses (generated by compiler) copy constructor, which does a shallow copy of object.

Your mistake is that member operator= meant to assign its argument's value to `this`. `operator=` return result of assignment, which can be used for chaining: `a=b=c;`

```
A& A::operator= (const A &right)
```

is equivalent of

```
A& operator= (A &left, const A &right)
```

Comment: There are no concepts of deep and shallow copy in C++.  A copy is a copy. It is whatever the copy constructor and assignment operators say it is. The two need to be consistent.  When we were puzzling this out in the mid eighties, we decided at the first C++ conference that the default copy-constructor would copy each component of the object, and so on recursively.  One might say, "That's deep." :-)

Comment: @JiveDadson shallow\deep copy is semantic concept , not a language concept. c++  by itself does ONLY a shallow copy. A shallow copy of an object copies all of the member field values. A deep copy copies all owned resources. Some languages always do  deep copy, some do only shallow copy, like C or C++.

Comment: I know how Java and Python people use the terms. I am a C++ people.  Copy?

Comment: Before the first C++ conference that I alluded to, the default copy constructor did a bit-for-bit copy. Now that's shallow.

Comment: @JiveDadson bit-to-bit explanation is invalid because object might have not a standard layout (C compatible). Fred Swartz and Bjarne Stroustrup use  those terms and that's as C++ people as they get. As well as nearly every lecturer at institutes That's essential terms to explain why compiler-generated copy constructor is not enough. I never touched Java and term comes from Ada, I think.

Comment: When Bjarne and I discussed what a copy-constructor should do at that first conference, he never used those terms. People change. I am stuck in my ways.

Comment: Well yeah, bit-for-bit was wrong. No argument there. Peace.

Comment: The terms pre-date Ada. Maybe even me, and that's some pre-dating, lemme tell you.

Comment: @JiveDadson interesting.. most of widely used languages that predate Ada are made or were propagated by same person (aside from C, of course). I imagine that it had meaning in some other area?

Comment: People used the terms in the C days of yesteryear. We had classes back then, we just had to work real hard for them.  And don't forget Simula 67.